# Angularjs, ContentEditable="true" , using ng-bind-html to render the content, I want the children elements of the ContentEditable div to be in a line

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a ContentEditable div in angularjs. Im using ng-bind-html to show some html while the page has been loaded. But the contents of the element are coming line by line, I want it to come side by side . Is there any way how can we achieve this ?

```
<div contentEditable="true" ng-bind-html="content"></div>
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auhgt7f3/2/)

Comment: you have them in divs which are block level elements.

Comment: what should i use instead of div's , to render them side by side

Comment: a span would do that...

Comment: I tried giving span, even that is not working , here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/auhgt7f3/3/

Comment: Thats because p tags taking full width of the container. For restricting that just add "display:inline block" style for the p tag. https://jsfiddle.net/auhgt7f3/4/. I have updated the fiddle. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

These are just HTML elements on your page, so you need to style them. The elements are all block elements, so do something like

```
#editor h1,
#editor div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```